# Parsing Data _Config Using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

i am trying to parse data in from one component to another.

Basically , I created 2 components. My intention is to create a dynamic component 
where anybody can just change email addressees to other email address by changing the content inside _errorConfig object which is  "email: "test@gmail.com" without touching anything in the logic side or ts file.

I also tried to parse string to button but after parsing , nothing changes , instead , it returns me error after it is clicked. For an example , i want to redirect it to " /App/Components/Contact " upon clicking .

, i will comment inside the code for your better understanding .

**example.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'example-error',
template: `
<kd-error-404 [_config]="_errorConfig">

</kd-error-404>
` 

})

export class ExampleError404 extends PageBase{

private _errorConfig : any = {

    //developer input
    homebtn : "/App/Components/Alert",
    //Developer input
    email : "test@gmail.com",
    };
}
```

This is the page where all the logic should be placed. 
**logic.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'kd-error-404',
templateUrl: '....'
})

export class KdError404 implements OnInit{

private _error: any = {};
private _defaultConfig : any = {
    homebtn: "/App/Components/Alert" , 
    email: "test@gmail.com"

}

@Input() _config: any;


ngOnInit(){
     console.log(this._config);

    if(typeof this._config == "undefined") this._error = Object.assign({}, this._defaultConfig );
     else {
        this._error.email = ( this._config.email != "undefined" ) ? this._config.email : "test@gmail.com"; 
        this._error.homebt = (this._config.homebtn != "undefined ") ? this._config.homebtn : "/App/Components/Alert";   
    }
}
constructor(
    protected _router: Router
){} 

 redirect(){
        this._router.navigate([_error._config.homebtn]);
 }


}
```

This is my html page where it is attached to logic.ts

this is where it should read based on user input for email . for an    example. user has input test@gmail.com on example.ts

**UPDATED**

I have already rectified the problem and i am able to parse the data for button. What i'm unsure with at the moment is that i am unsure how am i suppose to parse data as string to

based on what i have declared in example.ts , it should parse data to 
<  .. a href={{email}}>  to receive string as test@gmail.com

```
 <a href="">administrator</a>
 </p>
```

Comment: Can you reduce the un needed lines from code.. cant clarify the question..

Comment: parse string to button... Wow

Comment: I have already edited the question. sorry for the unneeded lines . P.S i have rectified the problem to parse string to button. now i am unsure how can i parse string "test@gmail.com" from example.ts to html 

<a href="mailto: {{should parse data here based on user input inside email for example.ts}}">Contact me: </a>